# MySQL LIMIT doesn't work

Tags: mysql

I have this table on my mysql database:

```
date       | client | total
2015-01-01 | john   | 85.00
2015-01-01 | alfred | 35.00
2015-01-01 | georgy | 125.00
2015-01-01 | linda  | 42.00
2015-01-01 | alex   | 76.00
2015-01-01 | john   | 94.00
2015-01-01 | john   | 75.30
```

I wanted to group by client name calculating total sum amount and percent, so I made this query:

```
SELECT client, total, round(total*100/t.th,1) as percent 
FROM ( 
    SELECT client, sum(total) as total 
    FROM mytable 
    WHERE date='2015-01-01' 
    GROUP BY `client`) c 
JOIN ( select sum(total) as th from mytable 
    WHERE date='2015-01-01') t 
order by percent desc
```

It works great but now I want to list only the 3 first results so I added at the end `LIMIT 3` but it doesn't work, it's still showing me the same number of results.

**UPDATE:**

When I execute this query I obtain:

```
client | total | percent
john   | 254.3 | 47.8
georgy | 125   | 23.5
alex   | 76    | 14.3
linda  | 42    | 7.9
alfred | 35    | 6.6
```

Until here is correct, but now I want only the 3 first rows, so I modify:

```
SELECT client, total, round(total*100/t.th,1) as percent 
FROM ( 
    SELECT client, sum(total) as total 
    FROM mytable 
    WHERE date='2015-01-01' 
    GROUP BY `client`) c 
JOIN ( select sum(total) as th from mytable 
    WHERE date='2015-01-01') t 
order by percent desc LIMIT 3
```

But it's not working, it's still showing the same results and I want this:

```
client | total | percent
john   | 254.3 | 47.8
georgy | 125   | 23.5
alex   | 76    | 14.3
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Since it should work *if* you just added the limit 3 at the end, show the query that doesn't work. They may be a typo or something.

Comment: There are some questions/issues with your query as written. Why use sub-queries? Where is the ON clause for the JOIN?

Comment: Where did u add the `LIMIT 3`?

Comment: Why are you selecting the same columns from a subquery. It doesn't seem to have a purpose. You could calculate the percent directly on sum(total)

Comment: I'm guessing you are using limit on your subquery and that is causing your problem.

Comment: Your query works fine for me. [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/490dd5/3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following query which storing no of rows for a particular date in a variable so that you don't need cross join:

```
select @rows := sum(total) from myTable where date = '2015-01-01';

SELECT client, total, round(total*100/@rows,1) as percent 
FROM ( 
    SELECT client, sum(total) as total 
    FROM mytable 
    WHERE date='2015-01-01' 
    GROUP BY `client`
     )
order by percent desc
LIMIT 3;
```

Alternatively, instead of writing 2 different queries, you can do the following:

```
SELECT client, total, round(total*100/total_sum,1) as percent 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT client, @total_sum:= @total_sum + sum(total) as total_sum, sum(total) as total 
        FROM mytable 
        WHERE date='2015-01-01' 
        GROUP BY `client`
         ), (select @total_sum:=0) as t
    order by percent desc
    LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: Hmm @rows is wrong. In the OP's code, they are dividing by the sum of total, not the count

Comment: @KodosJohnson thnx for that. Totally missed that. Edited the answer

Comment: @HarshilDoshi Thanks for answer but it shows me null in percent column, I updated my question

Comment: Both queries are returning null? If yes then can you provide create & insert queries or a sqlfiddle?

Comment: @HarshilDoshi I checked your link but I don't know what happen that in my case is showing same results and not only the first 3, I tried with your second query, it showed me error saying `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias` so I had to modify putting `GROUP BY client) a, (select @total_sum...` I want to order by total not by percent, and it works but percent column is showing NULL

Comment: i don't find anything wrong with your. It really strange it's not working for you. Is this query is part/inner query of some another outer query?

Comment: Also, my first query works here with providing alias to derived table. You can check & try it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8ae6/15/1

Comment: @HarshilDoshi Finally my works, it seems it's a problem of phpmyadmin where I'm executing queries, I had to execute queries via terminal and works fine, thanks for answer